# Why does Perry commit the murders in Capote?

Tags: capote

In the movie Capote, why does Perry go about shooting every family member in the face? One minute he's caused the throat slitting of the father in the family. The next thing you know he's going about killing everybody. Looks like he initially didn't intend to do this. What causes him to commit all the murders?

Comment: Note that while you probably really intended to ask Perry's motives in the movie, your question is actually asking the real Perry's motives in real-life (everything actually happened, more or less, for real). Googling around I see that nobody have actually managed to figure it out apart form "he's crazy"

Answer (score 5):

I would say you'd probably have to read the book ***In Cold Blood*** or research what you can of  Dick Hickock and Perry Smith. As it was (the crime) way back in '59 before the internet there is not a great deal of information. The book is probably the best way. Here is an excerpt of an article on this subject:

> Capote explores the motive again and again within his text, eventually concluding that any real motive for the crime lays within Perry — his feelings of inadequacy, his ambiguous sexuality, and his anger at the world and at his family because of his bad childhood. Dick plays the role of true outlaw, but the impact of the killings weighs heavily on him, and his own role in the murders remains unexplained and unclear. [CliffsNotes on *In Cold Blood*](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/i/in-cold-blood/book-summary)

Comment: funny that the movie didn't focus on the "why" given there was a scene depicting the brutal murders.

Comment: Yeah the movie the movie is great PSH steals the show of course. I always liked Infamous (2006) because Daniel Craig really got into the bad guy role and I remember think a little more depth. But I'll have to re watch the both again for a good comparison.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0420609/